# How can I use jquery to count the child divs within a parent div and display the order number within each child div?

Tags: html, jquery, webflow

I'm currently building a CMS gallery list within Webflow and I'd like to automatically display a number within each individual child div.

I can see that I probably need to implement some sort of jquery code and I'm struggling rewrite existing solutions.

In the code below, I want to count the number of children within .feature-slider_list and then display the child order number within .feature-slider_number.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```css
.feature-slider_item {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

.feature-slider_wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.feature-slider_number {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: 30px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #00d6d6;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-6deg);
    transform: rotate(-6deg);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature-slider_list">
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add jQuery code to loop through the slider items and add index.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.feature-slider_list').children().each(function (index) {
      $(this).find('.feature-slider_number').html(index+1);
  });
  }
)
```

```css
.feature-slider_item {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

.feature-slider_wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.feature-slider_number {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: 30px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #00d6d6;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-6deg);
    transform: rotate(-6deg);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature-slider_list">
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just `$('.feature-slider-number').html(i => i +1);`

Comment: Yes, if there won't be a chance of having multiple sliders in the same page.

Comment: This has worked beautifully. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `::after` and `content` with `attr`. And I added `height:100%` to `feature-slider_item` and  `bottom: -30px;` to `.feature-slider_number`   to fix that one element with an index was not showing up.

```css
.feature-slider_item {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

.feature-slider_wrap {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
}
.feature-slider_number::after {
  content: attr(index);
}
.feature-slider_number {
  
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: -30px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #00d6d6;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-6deg);
    transform: rotate(-6deg);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature-slider_list">
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number" index="1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number" index="2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number" index="3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-slider_item">
    <div class="feature-slider_wrap">
      <img src="" class="feature-slider_image">
      <div class="feature-slider_number" index="4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code is automatically generated from Webflow, so I would need to bolt on something to change the result of the number. Thank you though!